# Adding dice to checks in Pathfinder: Rise of the Runelord

Tags: pathfinder-adventure

In the [FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1gk#v5748eaic9rde), a point says

> **Choices Matter**. Your choices have consequences. (...) If you roll too low on a Combat check, it’s too late to play a Strength spell to improve your result.

Does that mean I have to play all the 'discard this card to add a die to a check' cards **before** attempting the check? E.g, I'm doing some combat check, I need 8 to beat it. I roll my hand-to-hand combat strength check, and get a 6. Can I now discard a BotG to add another die to the result, and try to beat the test?

[image]

Or would I have to specify **before** the check that I would discard the BotG to get an extra die?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You must play all cards that will modify the check before making the check.**

According to the [rules](http://paizo.com/download/pathfinder/PZO6000-Rulebook.zip) (starting on page 11), each check is broken into a number of steps. In order (emphasis mine):

> 1. Determine Which Die You're Using.
> 2. Determine the Difficulty.
> 3. **Play Cards and Use Powers That Affect the Check (Optional).**
> 4. Assemble Your Dice.
> 5. Attempt the Roll.
> 6. Take Damage, If Necessary.

Step three is where you would discard your *Blessing of the Gods* in order to add the die. If you make it to step five, where you make the roll, it is now too late to play any cards or powers to modify have the check is made.